# Django ORM queryset to table with one field as index, using a json response

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django ORM table called Measurements as below:

```
| pk | Length | Width | Height | Weight | Date       |
|----|--------|-------|--------|--------|------------|
| 1  | 131    | 23    | 52     | 126    | 2019-12-01 |
| 2  | 136    | 22    | 64     | 125    | 2019-12-02 |
| 3  | 124    | 25    | 59     | 130    | 2019-12-03 |
```

As can be observed, Length, Width, Height, Weight & Date are all fields.

I want to send a json response such that it can be used to render a table like below:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Measurement | 2019-12-01 | 2019-12-02 | 2019-12-03 |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Length      | 131        | 136        | 124        |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Width       | 23         | 22         | 25         |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Height      | 52         | 64         | 59         |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Weight      | 126        | 125        | 130        |
+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

To do this I will have to return a list of 4 dictionaries where each dictionary in the list will have the following keys: `Measurement`, `2019-12-01`, `2019-12-02`, `2019-12-03`. Like so:

```
>>> dicts = [
...     { "Measurement": "Length", "2019-12-01": 131, "2019-12-02": 136,"2019-12-03": 124 },
...     { "Measurement": "Width", "2019-12-01": 23, "2019-12-02": 22,"2019-12-03": 25 },
...     { "Measurement": "Height", "2019-12-01": 52, "2019-12-02": 64,"2019-12-03": 59 },
...     { "Measurement": "Weight", "2019-12-01": 126, "2019-12-02": 125,"2019-12-03": 130 }
... ]
```

I am currently using a very long & convoluted way of doing it. I first create a dataframe using the queryset. Then I set index as the date column followed by using the `df.to_dict()` method to create a list of dictionaries. This however creates dictionaries with `datetime` objects as keys, which cannot be dumped to json. So I again have to loop over a copy of the list to fix the keys. I feel I am doing way too much work to get this done & that there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use serializers if you're already using DRF?

Comment: Would the serializers provide the required output given how my table is structured? We recently switched to DRF from MVT & my co-dev told me that serializers would just jsonify responses of already existing views? As per DRF docs, anything you can't dump as a json in python wouldn't constitute a valid json REST response & like I have mentioned, most of the keys are datetime objects. I am curious to know if there's a more straight-forward approach using serializers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use `pandas`? If so, there is a short solution.

```
df = df.drop(['pk'], axis=1)
# convert datetime to string in a given format
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
df.transpose()
```

Oh, just saw that you want a json response. It is also straight-forward:

```
json_response = [dict(s) for _, s in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: Nice! I forgot that I could transpose the df. So.. I made some additions/changes to your code above & got it to work. Problem is, like before, there are still datetime keys in the dictionary. Is there anyway to fix that during the list comprehension?

Comment: See added line.

Comment: Thanks a ton Kate! It works like a charm! I will post an answer with my changes/additions for anybody else who might need it because I can't do it here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
dates = [obj.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for obj in queryset]
fields = [length, width, height, weight]
dicts = []
for field in fields:
    row = {"Measurement": field}
    i = 0
    for object in queryset:
        row[dates[i]] = getattr(object, field, '') 
        i += 1
    dicts.append(row)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! However, the format that you provided for rows was what I previously used for bootstrap tables. But we recently moved to REST + vue.js & the data is now required to be in the format I mentioned in the question. Do you think you can modify your code to arrive at the result?

Comment: Do you actually have capital letters in model fields?

Comment: Nope, I don't have capital letters. Sorry, that was just for the question. It's all lowercase. BTW, i tried the updated answer & I am getting an AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute <Insert field name here>. Any ideas? Edit: Sorry I just saw that you updated the answer again. trying right now.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting the same AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute <Insert field name here> on the latest answer. Can't figure out why because the individual queryset objects definitely have the attribute being requested with getattr.

Comment: Please try again, with new updates - lowercase letters.

Comment: I handled all of the field names actually. It's quite a long list of fields so I load them programatically, so it's no problem. But now I know why I am getting the AttributeError. Because not all fields are present in all queryset objects. So some of the values are actually None. You can think of it like one of the length measurements wasn't taken so it's none in the queryset object. Is there any way around this? I would also request you to find a way to typecast the keys from datetime to string because otherwise I can't dump to json.

Comment: Just tried the latest answer. The dictionaries are exactly the way I want them but the value for all keys (other Measurement key) is ''.

Comment: this means that `getattr(object, field, '')` doesn't get the fields from your queryset objects. Could you please show the code of your Measurements model, and the code where you build queryset.

Comment: So I tried isolating an individual dictionary from the queryset and using getattr on it by passing an attribute i know exists because I can see it. Still raises an AttributeError. Same case with dot notation. However, if I call the same attribute using square brackets it returns the value just fine. Something funny going on. I would love to paste some of my code but both my ORM model declaration & the actual query are too long. I would have to explain too many irrelevant things. Moreover, like I explained, I think this could just be something to with Django itself.

Comment: In this case, just change `getattr(object, field, '')` to `object.get(field, '')`

Comment: Thanks Andrey! That did the trick! Can you please elaborate on why this(object.get) worked & the getattr didn't? Also, I have posted an answer to this that also seems to do the trick. Can you weigh in on which one would be faster/better?

Comment: For some reason, your queryset is dictionary, rather than a model queryset object. You cannot access dictionary with getattr

Comment: Ah yes.. That could be because of the values() method I use to pull down only the specified fields.

Answer (score 0):

```py
measurements = [
    “Length”, “Width”, “Height”, “Weight”
]

output = []
for m in measurements:
  # creates dict of { first : second }
  # so we should have { date : value }
  single = dict(
      Measurement.objects.values_list(
        “Date”, m
      )
  )
  single[“Measurement”] = m
  output.append(single)
```

This code is untested, but I have used the idea before. I suppose this would hit the database an unnecessary number of times so it depends on your needs and backend.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! The queryset actually pulls down hundreds of rows & I have a lot more fields than what I gave in the MRE. So I suppose, like you mentioned, this might end up hitting the database way too many times for a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Using my earlier code & code provided my user kate-melynkova, I have come with a nice solution for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(queryset).replace({np.nan:None})
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
tdf = df.transpose()
tdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
json_response = [dict(s) for _, s in tdf.iterrows()]
```

PS. I am leaving out the `df.drop()` method from kate's answer because I am assuming that you would be using the `values()` method to pass only the fields that you require while making the query. If you're not, feel free to use the `df.drop()` & pass in a list with whichever fields you want dropped.